# Animation glitch when closing a modal while keyboard is visible

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Ive noticed an issue when closing a modal while the keyboard is up.  There is a weird animation where the modal pops to the lower left as the keyboard goes away during the closing animation.

Ive tried to hide the keyboard before closing the modal but that doesn't seem to help.

Ive also looked in to making sure the keyboard is fully gone first, then activating the close animation, but I can't figure out any sort of way to do that with blocks etc.  and adding the close modal to the keyboardWillHide notification methods will break a million things elsewhere since it is already implemented for other reasons.

Has anyone seen this kind of issue before?

code to dismiss modal

```
    [formNavigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    formNavigationController = nil;
    }];
```

Comment: I have a view controller that is dismissed modally with the keyboard up. Can you post some code so that I can see how you're doing it?

Also, try not resigningFirstResponder on the first responder when dismissing.

Comment: I added the code i use to dismiss

Comment: resigning the first responder was the problem

Comment: im calling it from a parent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34087/discussion-between-mark-and-jmd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not resigning the first responder when you dismiss.